# Decide and prove whether this function is differentiable at $x_0 = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis

Decide and prove whether

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if } & x < 0 \\[2ex]
1, & \text{if } & x \ge 0
\end{cases}$

is differentiable at $x_0 = 0 $

I know that

[If this limit exists then it is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEBgh.jpg)

However I think this limit doesn't for the above function but how do I go about proving it?

Comment: Examine the behavior of $\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$ for $h$ approaching zero from the positive numbers, and for $h$ approaching zero from the negative numbers. What does it happen?

Comment: Is the limit the same when you take the limit coming from the left AND the right?  You need continuity...

Comment: Show the limit from the left differs from the limit from the right.

Comment: Also, differentiability implies continuity...if your function is differentiable, then it must be continuous.  Is your function continuous?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $x_n=\frac{(-1)^n}n$. It is clear that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=0$, but 
$$f(x_{2n})=1\implies \limsup_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = 1 $$
and
$$f(x_{2n+1})=1\implies \liminf_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = 0,$$
so $f(x_n)$ does not converge. We conclude that $f$ is not continuous at $0$ (and hence not differentiable at $0$).

Answer (score 0):

We know that if a function is differentiable at a point $x_0$, then it is continuous.

Now just take the contrapositive statement and you get

"If a function is not continuous at a point $x_0$, then it is not differentiable".

It is clear from the statements above that taking left and right limits will provide the discontinuity at $x_0=0$ and therefore, the function is not differentiable at $x_0=0$.